# CSS background colour is different between IE and Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, colors

I am setting `color:#0080FF;` and it is showing as a skyblue colour in the visual studio editor, but when I run it in internet explorer it is not giving the appropriate colour.

The problem lies in IE, because when I changed the browser to Chrome, it displayed the correct colour that I want to apply.

I also converted `color:#0080FF;` to `color:rgb(0, 128, 255);` but no success.

I feel like I am lost now. Any solutions?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot with two browsers showing different colors?

Answer (score 2):

Different browsers some time render colors differently. A possible solution is , try some other color which works uniformly throughout .

[MSDN Link of Bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/6757da6e-5aa4-4219-8c31-c3dfc992c6eb/ie-does-not-render-images-the-correct-color?forum=iewebdevelopment)

Comment: do you have resource for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using web safe colors it should be the same on all browsers. You can find them with a simple Google search.

Answer (score 0):

try image as background to i.e browsers

```
 example

 .yourclass{

    /*if ie 
     background: url(path/image)*/

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]I do not see any difference on my machine, I know works on my machine. I setup  JSFiddle and took a screen shot. http://jsfiddle.net/docluv/ExLwd/

```
.blue{
   background-color:#0080FF;
   color:#fff;
   height:20em;
   width:20em;
}
```